# Удаление пробелов и переводов строк

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Для того что б вырезать все пробелы и переводы строк, как с начала, так и с конца, + убирать двойные пробелы, написал регулярку:

```
$opis =~ s/^\s+|^(\r?\n)+|\s+$|(\r?\n)+$//g;
$opis =~ s/\s+/ /g;
```

Локально все работает, как только запускаю на сервере, работать не хочет.
Вернее оно удаляет вообще все переводы строк, даже те, что есть в середине текста. Почему?

Comment: Уточните под каким OS / Perl работает локально и на сервере

Comment: локально активперл

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\s` в регулярном выражении означает и перевод каретки в том числе, поэтому в середине строки исчезают переводы. используйте `\h`

```
$opis =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
$opis =~ s/\h+/ /g;
```

Comment: круто, странно что я нигде это не встречал в доках.
спасибо!

Comment: где почитать о вышесказанном можно?
в часности о \h ?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html тут

Comment: точно, еще раз спасибо
\h [3]  Horizontal whitespace

Comment: А что самое классное, что теперь мне не надо выделываться, а грамотно обработать тело можно так: 

    $opis =~ s/(\s)+/$1/g;
Вместо `$opis =~ s/\h+/ /g;` это позволит избавиться от 2 кареток в том числе. Все верно?

Comment: да, все верно

Answer (score 1):

Потому что g в конце поставил.
Рекомендую начальные/конечные пробелы убирать одной регуляркой (или двумя), а двойные переводы строк другой, уже с g.

Comment: Вот так:

    $opis =~ s/^[\r\n\s]+//;
    $opis =~ s/[\r\n\s]+$//g;
    $opis =~ s/\s+/ /g;

Comment: убрал, не помогло. хотя я так и думал что /g ни при чем тут

Comment: и регулярки поправь как ниже отписались )))

Answer (score -1):

```
$opis=~s/\s{2,}|\n//g
```